# One procedure to insert and update query

Tags: sql-server

One procedure to insert and update query

Comment: How on earth should **anyone** be able to answer this?!??!?!?! Could you be a **bit** more specific??? What table structure? What data? How do you want to insert + update ????

Comment: One procedure to insert them all, 
One procedure to select them,
one procedure to update them all,
and in darkness delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableName
       (column1, column2)
 VALUES
       (values1, value2);

SELECT * FROM TableName;
```